# Using box-shadow to create inner border for image

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create an inner border to an image using box-shadow. I'm using code I copied from a CSS generator and it does not work on my image. How can I get this code to work with my image?

I am trying to make a top and a bottom border only. No sides.

http://codepen.io/trevoray/pen/NPxyzG

```css
.bannerImages {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -17px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -17px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -17px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<img class="bannerImages" src="http://webtest-community.canoo.com/wiki/space/SnipSnap/config/webtest_tag_rgb_pos_small.jpg" />
```

Comment: Whyt not user `border: 1px solid #000` and `box-sizing: border-box`?

Comment: See- http://designbystevie.com/2011/03/applying-css3-inset-box-shadows-to-images/

Comment: Paulie_D, I'm attempting to create only top and bottom border.

Comment: Are you actually creating a box shadow, or are you just wanting a solid border that overlaps the image? If it's the latter, you might want to consider different approach; Farhan's box-shadow solution can easily be adjusted to work with just borders. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's how](http://codepen.io/farhan687/pen/xbZYQj). The trick is to wrap your image in another element and use an absolutely positioned `before` pseudo-element.

Comment: Farhan, that is close, but I'm also going to be adding a top border of same width. How do I do that with your solution?

Comment: change the 'box-shadow' to 'box-shadow: inset 0px -3px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1), inset 0px 3px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,1);'

Comment: [link](http://codepen.io/farhan687/pen/xbZYQj) just play with box-shadow in before of imgContainer class. check my link to get better idea.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `outline` to get a border inside the image

```css
.bannerImages  {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  outline-offset: -4px;   
}
```

```html
<img class="bannerImages" src="http://webtest-community.canoo.com/wiki/space/SnipSnap/config/webtest_tag_rgb_pos_small.jpg" />
```

More info: http://caniuse.com/#search=outline

Comment: I can't use outline because I want a top and bottom border. Not an entire border.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using an inset box-shadow on an image appears to be that the shadow is rendered behind the image.

If you really have your heart set on using a box-shadow, you will need an image with a transparent background... (Convert your jpg to png and delete the background)

```css
.bannerImages {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 7px 10px -4px #000 inset, 0px -7px 10px -4px #000 inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 7px 10px -4px #000 inset, 0px -7px 10px -4px #000 inset;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 10px -4px #000 inset, 0px -7px 10px -4px #000 inset;
}
```

```html
<img class="bannerImages" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCgfw.png" />
```